# neo4j apoc.load.json: load all files from a directory

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

In Neo4j, How can I call apoc.load.json on all files that are in a directory?
Is there any cypher command to interact with the system directory?
Or si there apoc function/procedure?

Comment: Hey guys !!!! Apo.load.json is about coding in neo4j ... why the hell is it off-topic?